# Accessing value from callback in ctypes

Tags: c++, python, c, pointers, ctypes

I'm using Python/ctypes to write an app based on a commercial DLL. This DLL reads a flatfile and returns data through `struct`s. The relevant C `struct`s looks like this:

```
struct System{
    unsigned short       user;
    unsigned short       version;
};

struct Message {
    unsigned short       header;
    unsigned short       data;
    unsigned int         messageType;
};
```

The API that came with the DLL provides a pointer to a function with the following prototype. This function loops through the flatfile and calls `Callback` defined next:

```
typedef int (__stdcall *Process) (const char* filename, const char* base, unsigned int flags, int user, Callback stdcallback);
```

and the `Callback` prototype (the fifth argument above) is defined as:

```
typedef int (__stdcall *Callback) (const System* Sys, const Message* Msg);
```

In my python file:

```
from ctypes import *

# using WinDLL for stdcall
lib = WinDLL('CVO.dll')

class System(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('user', c_ushort),
                ('version', c_ushort)]

class Message(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('header', c_ushort),
                ('data', c_ushort),
                ('messageType', c_uint)]

PROTO = WINFUNCTYPE(c_int, POINTER(System), POINTER(Message))

def py_callbck(Sys, Msg):
    print Msg._type_.messageType
    # return 0 to read the next line in the flatfile
    return 0

Callback = PROTO(py_callbck)

pProcess lib.Process
pProcess.argtypes = [c_char_p,c_char_p,c_uint,c_int,PROTO]
pProcess.restype = c_int

pProcess(c_char_p('flat.ccf'),c_char_p(None),c_uint(0),c_int(0),Callback)
```

My problem lies in accessing the value the DLL passes to the `Msg` struct. The code should be printing an `c_int` (0, 1, 2) but instead is returning a `Field` type like such:

```
<Field type=c_ulong, ofs=136, size=4>
```

I know the flatfile is being processed, because my Python code prints out hundreds of the `<Field ...>` statements, which it is supposed to do.

My question is how I can access the value the DLL is pushing to the `Msg` `Structure` instead of returning `<Field ...>` statements?

Note I'm relatively new to ctypes and have very little C so if you notice issues with defining anything, please let me know. For example, I know there is a difference between `ctypes.pointer` which returns and object and `ctypes.POINTER` which returns a new type. When I use `ctypes.pointer` the code errors out.

Answer (score 1):

For being relatively new to ctypes you've done a pretty good job here. The `_type_` attribute of a pointer is a reference to the pointed at data type. In this case it's `Message`. The class attribute `messageType` is the `CField` data descriptor used by an instance.

What you want to do instead is dereference the pointer to get a `Message` instance. You can either use a `[0]` subscript or the `contents` attribute:

```
def py_callbck(Sys, Msg):
    print Msg[0].messageType  # Msg.contents.messageType
    # return 0 to read the next line in the flatfile
    return 0
```

---

Remember to retain a reference to `Callback` to keep it from being garbage collected. Currently you reference it as a global. That's fine.

Regarding the way you're calling `pProcess`, it's generally unnecessary to manually create ctypes objects for simple types when you've defined `argtypes`. You can more simply use the following:

```
pProcess('flat.ccf', None, 0, 0, Callback)
```

But pay attention to whether the function needs a writable string buffer. In that case use `create_string_buffer`. It's unnecessary here since the `char *` parameters are both `const`.